# convert MultiLabelDataset<String, String> to Guava Multimap for printing / examining

Tags: java, string, apache, output, guava

I'm working with the following program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String input = args[0];

    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( input ) );

    toMultiLabelDataset(is);
    is.close();
}

public static MultiLabelDataset<String, String> toMultiLabelDataset(InputStream is) throws IOException
{
    List<RelationAndMentions> relations = toRelations(is, true);
    MultiLabelDataset<String, String> dataset = toDataset(relations);

    return dataset;
}
```

As you can see it utilizes a data structure of the form `MultiLabelDataset<String, String>`, I want to print the contents of that beast in a human intelligabe form. According to my previous searching I can likely use apache string utils or google guava library, is that right? How would I go about going that?

My guess would be that theres an equivalent data struc in those libraries, one that takes `<String, String>`, I just need to determine what that is, copy the contents of `MultiLabelDataset<String, String>` and then print? Is that reasonable?

### **EDIT**

---

```
    Multimap<String, String> result = HashMultimap.create();
    for (String key : ((MultiLabelDataset) dataset).items) 
    {
        for (String value : dataset.getLabels()) 
        {
            result.put(key, value);
        }
    }
```

^not like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's this [MultiLabelDataset](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/api/edu/stanford/nlp/tmt/data/MultiLabelDataset.html), then it's similar to Guava's [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) and you can convert it easily. However, this conversion will be neither simpler nor smarter than a direct conversion to a `String`. The only advantage would be that thereafter you can work with a sane Java class having many useful method and working well together with other Java classes.

The whole conversion goes like always, but you need something to iterate the keys. Assuming the only implementation is LabeledLDADataset, it's easy:

```
Multimap<String, String> toMultimap(MultiLabelDataset<String, String> dataset) {
    Multimap<String, String> result = HashMultimap.create();
    for (Item key : ((LabeledLDADataset) dataset).items()) {
        result.putAll(key.toString(), dataset.getLabels(key));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: yeah! it's exactly that!

Comment: so, at this point all I want to do is print the contents in a clean way and get a look at whats inside, but it's concievable that I'll want to do more later. if its not too much trouble perhaps you can show me just a quick and dirty way to print it to a string or w/e, maybe then later i can read through the multimap documentation

Comment: @S.Matthew_English This information belongs to the question, not to the answer. Unless you wanted to train us in googling. +++ I'm actually unsure what's the exact question... sure it can be converted to something using two nested loops, but is it worth it?

Comment: at the risk of appearing daft, i suppose that `LabeledLDADataset` refers to `MultiLabelDataset` i guess but what is `thingy` referencing? I edited my original post to demonstrate my failed attempt.

Comment: @S.Matthew_English Sorry for the identifier... I find the class name rather appalling, so I wanted to avoid referring to it again. And [LabeledLDADataset](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/api/edu/stanford/nlp/tmt/model/llda/LabeledLDADataset.html) is the only subclass listed in the Javadoc. And if the cast fails, then you're out of luck (and have to find out what exact class you've been given).

Comment: I figured out the include thing, it's the stanford tmt jar but now there's an error in my ide about the line `result.putAll( key, dataset.getLabels( key ));` it says that it can't resolve `getLabels` for a String, do you know how to fix that? I guess it doesn't like `key` for some reason.